# Javascript parseInt function not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am comparing two integer values coming from two text boxes using javascript but it is not working.

```js
JavaScript:
function update_total(){
var available = ParseInt(document.getElementById('available_qty').value,10);
var sale_qty = ParseInt(document.getElementById('selling_qty').value,10);
if(sale_qty>available){
alert('Re-enter sale quantity');
}
}
```

```html
HTML:
<input type="text" name="available_qty" id="available_qty" />
<input type="text" name="selling_qty" id="selling_qty"onChange="update_total();"/>
```

No alert is generated in case sale quantity is greater than available. How to do it?

Comment: should be `parseInt` instead of `ParseInt`

Comment: It is advisable to read [MDN] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference) docs for reference before posting questions related to api usage

Comment: @RaviTiwari, For such errors, one need to read `console` than `MDN` :)

Comment: @Rayon : It may be hard many a times to understand just a sentence as `js:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: ParseInt is not defined` and figure out what went wrong. 
But yes, if you have seen many, then no better friend than `console` :)

Comment: Though for a capitalisation typo you might stare at it all day and just not see it. I can't tell you how many times I've typed `functoin`, but I'm pretty used to seeing the (parse time) error…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

JS is case sensitive, so it must be [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) (first lower-case letter)

```js
function update_total() {
  var available = parseInt(document.getElementById('available_qty').value, 10);
  var sale_qty = parseInt(document.getElementById('selling_qty').value, 10);
  if (sale_qty > available) {
    alert('Re-enter sale quantity');
  }
}
```

```html
HTML:
<input type="text" name="available_qty" id="available_qty" />
<input type="text" name="selling_qty" id="selling_qty" onChange="update_total();" />
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript:
(you have a syntax error in parseInt)

```
function update_total(){
  var available = parseInt(document.getElementById('available_qty').value,10);
  var sale_qty = parseInt(document.getElementById('selling_qty').value,10);
  if(sale_qty>available){
    alert('Re-enter sale quantity');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is `parseInt(string[, radix])` and not `ParseInt`.

Answer (score 0):

Open your Developer Tools. Look at the Console.

> js:16 Uncaught ReferenceError: ParseInt is not defined

JavaScript is case-sensitive. It is spelt `parseInt`.

Comment: Thanks all for correcting my mistake.